# jQuery Mobile Updating page style after Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am unable to change background color/image after a successful ajax call with jquery mobile.

This is the code I am using. Following function is called after successful ajax call.

```
function apply_customisations(tmpCustomisations) {
    var customisations = JSON.parse(tmpCustomisations);
    console.log(customisations.inputBackColor);
    $('.ui-page, .ui-panel-wrapper').css('background', customisations.inputBackColor + ' !important');
    $('.ui-header .topbar').css('background', customisations.inputhfColor + ' !important');
    $('#btnBegin').css('background', '#FFF !important');
}
```

PAGE HTML MARK UP ---

```
<div data-role="page" id="introPage" data-theme="a" class="pagetype">

    <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <div class="topbar">
            <span class="titleOnTopBar">Question Intro</span>
            <a href="#" onclick="history.back(-1)" class="leftOnTopBar"><img class="topBackButton" src="menu_icons/back-btn.png" /></a>
            <!--<a href="#externalpanel" class="rightOnTopBar"><img class="topMenuButton" src="menu_icons/menu-btn.png" /></a>-->
        </div>
    </header>

    <div data-role="content" style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="queIntro"></div>
        <button id="btnBegin" onclick="begin()" class="blueThemeButton">Begin</button>
        <div id="dataPopulate"></div>
    </div>

    <footer data-role="footer" class="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-hide-during-focus="" data-theme="none">
        <nav data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="btnFavourite"><img src="img/info-icon.png" class="footer_icon"/>Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="btnHelp"><img src="img/help-icon.png" class="footer_icon"/>Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="btnContact"><img src="img/contact-icon.png" class="footer_icon"/>Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>
</div><!-- /page -->
```

As you can see above I am trying to change background color of three elements but none of the above works. For the last element in the function I pass #FFF value just to be sure that the correct hex value is being passed.

I also did following but it did not solve the problem.

```
$('.ui-page, .ui-panel-wrapper').trigger("pagecreate");
```

Comment: What version of jQM are you using? Also, please show the markup of the page so we can see what these 3 elements look like.

Comment: you can't use `!important` with `.css()`.

Comment: Page HTML added. I am using JQM version 1.4.1

Comment: @Omar is right. I ended up using     $('.ui-page, .ui-panel-wrapper').attr('style', 'background:' + customisations.inputBackColor + ' !important');